# pyproject.toml exclude some Python sources .py from data directory

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a data folder which contains a script which is only needed during development preparing some data.

```
|--mypackage 
|--mypackage/data 
|--mypackage/data/prepare.py
```

The problem is that this py file is included in the package. I tried to exclude it with:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
exclude = ["mypackage*data*py"]
```

But this does not seem the correct syntax. Or maybe it is not supported to exclude py files?