pyproject.toml config using setuptools with correct packages automatically
I build wheels using a setuptools-based pyproject.toml.
Here's the relevant bit:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64", "setuptools_scm>=8"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = [
    # ... long, and fragile, list
]

exclude = [
    # This, or similar syntaxes, don't seem to actually work.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/75091671/339144
]  # exclude packages matching these glob patterns (empty by default)

However, this is fragile because of the "long list"; every time I add a top-level package to my project layout (I use a flat, i.e. non-src layout) I have to remember adding it to the list.
How to solve this in the general way?

Use the src layout. That's what it's for. -- Here is setuptools' documentation about "import package" discovery: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/package_discovery.html.

re src: that means my installer dictates the layout of my project, which would seem the wrong way around. But thanks for the suggested workaround!

I do not understand what you mean with "my installer dictates the layout of my project". The installer is typically pip. setuptools is the "build backend". I do not know what is wrong with following conventions, it helps avoid the kind of situation you are in. -- Note also that the convention is to have one and only one top-level import package per project. -- For the rest setuptools should be able to automatically find the list of import packages anyway, it's in the setuptools documentation.

you're right, I mixed up terms; the "conventions" you speak of post-date my conventions, which is what I mean by dictating :-)
